# error using setTimeout with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have the following success method.  Before I was using the setTime out it worked without issue but it sent a lot of AJAX requests.  To try to slow it down I used setTimeout.  Since I put that in I get a bunch of these errors: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data === '') {
        setTimeout( $.ajax(this) ,3000);
        console.log("AJAX resent");

    }
    else {
        //console.log("|", data, "|");
        test.html('');
        test.append(data);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function must be referenced, not evaluated, so if you need to pass parameters, you'll have to wrap it in an anonymous function :

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax(that);
} ,3000);
```

Comment: Just put that inside the success function?

Comment: Yes, just replace the current timeout with this one, and remember that a new function creates a new scope, so you'll need a reference to `this`.

Comment: Woops, just saw that, deleting, deleting, and deleting.